# how to convert the pure soap php to laravel 5

Tags: soap, laravel-5

I am new in laravel 5. This code is ok in pure php. But I don't know how to convert this to laravel 5. Can you tell me how to transfer this code to laravel 5.

client.php:

```
<?php class client {
public function __construct()
{
    $params = array('location' => 'http://localhost:8888/csoap/server.php',
                    'uri' => 'urn://localhost:8888/csoap/server.php');

    /* Initialize webservice */
    $this->instance = new SoapClient(NULL, $params);
}

public function getString($id)
{
    return $this->instance->__soapCall('getOutputString', $id);
}
}

$client = new client();
$id = array('id' => '1');

echo $client->getString($id);
?>
```

csoap/server.php:

```
<?php class server {
public function getOutputString($id)
{
    $str = 'Youre ID is ' . $id . '.';
    return $str;
}
}

$params = array('uri' => 'http://localhost:8888/csoap/server.php');
$server =  new SoapServer(NULL, $params);
$server->setClass('server');
$server->handle();

?>
```

**This is how I performed my installation in laravel 5.1**

```
"require": {
        "artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.2.*"
    }
```

run: composer install or composer update

Add the service in config/app.php.

```
'providers' => [ 
...
...
Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider', 
]

'aliases' => [
...
...
'SoapWrapper' => 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper'
]
```

This is my client soap:

```
use Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper;

class DataSoap {

public function demo()
{
    // Add a new service to the wrapper
    SoapWrapper::add(function ($service) {
        $service
            ->name('mydata')
            ->wsdl('http://localhost:8888/csoap/Server.php')
            ->trace(true)
    });

    $data = [
        'str' => 'Hello World',
    ];

    // Using the added service
    SoapWrapper::service('mydata', function ($service) use ($data) {
        var_dump($service->getFunctions());
        var_dump($service->call('getString', [$data])->getSringResult);
    });
}
}
```

When I run the this code, I get an error

```
Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: Maybe try using a package: https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

Comment: @haakym where and how to put these class_alias('Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper', 'SoapWrapper');

Comment: You're using lumen or laravel?

Comment: in the code above I'm using pure php but I want to convert it to laravel 5.1.

Comment: Now I got an error... FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146: Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Follow the instructions for laravel not lumen

Comment: I followed the instructions but I got an error and its says: FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider' not found.. btw I'm using laravel 5.1.

Comment: Can you update your question adding how you performed the installation and your current code which is making the error occur. Thanks

Comment: I've updated already the codes.

Comment: Try taking some action based on the error. The error is telling you the class can't be found, so perhaps your setup is lacking something or the package didn't install properly. You could try `composer dump-autoload` and double checking the Soap package is installed properly by checking your composer files ( it should be in `composer.json` and `autoload_classmap.php`) and if that fails double check the steps for installation.

Answer (score 1):

You should change:

```
Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider
```

to:

```
Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\ServiceProvider::class
```

and also:

```
SoapWrapper' => 'Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper
```

to:

```
SoapWrapper' => Artisaninweb\SoapWrapper\Facades\SoapWrapper::class
```

Comment: also to note after updating config/app.php with L5's ::class syntax run composer dump-autoload